# How do I delete an equation in Grapher?

Tags: grapher

What it says in the title. There is no obvious way for me to remove an equation in Grapher. I used Grapher a few years ago and I probably knew how to then, but I cannot remember now.

Answer (score 8):

Click the equation in the sidebar and press ⌫backspace.

[image]